# SQL Server doesn't use index while chekcing the value of input parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

Could you please tell me why SQL Server does not use an index when I have this `@DocumentID IS NULL` condition in my where clause.

```
DECLARE @DocumentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'B8E16012-6D4B-4C86-8BC1-001143015F63'

SELECT  
    i.DepartmentID,
    vi.DocumentID  
FROM  
    dbo.VoucherItem vi
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Invoice i ON vi.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Department d on 1=1 
WHERE 
    (@DocumentID IS NULL 
     OR 
     vi.DocumentID = @DocumentID)
```

Comment: Well, if you remove this `@DocumentID IS NULL OR` from the `WHERE` you see the usage of the index in the query plan?

Comment: @King.code: Sure, but I need it. How can I have both usage of index and that condition?

Comment: Make this 2 select statements depending on @DocumentId being null or not. Use na optimize for unknown hint or a with recompile hint to tell SQL Server to reevaluate the condiution on EVERY CALL - (much slower). Otherwise you hit parameter sniffing anyway.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194253/sql-server-comparing-to-null-very-slow/27194734#27194734

Comment: @Martin Smith: Are you really sure they are the same?!. I asked about the reason while that question just need a solution?