# Same query has different execution plan in SP

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, performance

When the exact same query is placed within a stored procedure, it's generating an entirely different executing plan which takes ~ 18 seconds.

Versus when I run solo (and just DECLARE the variables above the query) it runs substantially faster ~ 1-2 seconds.

What can I do so that the query in the SP runs using the execution plan when run solo? FYI, I've even reproduced the issue by creating an entirely new stored procedure and literally copy-pasting the query into it. Same results of ~ 18 seconds.

The query is shown below for reference

```
select
    COUNT(b.BookKey) as RowCounter
from
    Books b (nolock) 
    inner join BookPublishRegions bp (nolock)
      on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey               
where           
    b.IsUnavailable = 0 and 
    (@AuthorKey is null or b.AuthorKey = @AuthorKey) and
    (b.Price between @MinPrice and @MaxPrice) and
    contains(bp.PublishRegionName, @SearchTerm)
```

I have indexes on b.IsUnavailable, b.AuthorKey, b.Price and a full-text index on bp.PublishRegionName.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Parameter sniffing might be a cause. This might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194253/sql-server-comparing-to-null-very-slow/27194734#27194734

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosBetsos . I've attempted the solution where SearchTerm is declared as a local variable and set to the parameter's value (as per recommended solution in that post) and it still did not do the trick. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Correction the above comment. I've set another local variable for AuthorKey, and now it's running quick again... Does this mean I have to set new local variables for all parameters used in my stored procs??

Comment: To disable parameter sniffing you need to declare a local variable for each input variable used in a where clause

Comment: You can avoid all the local variable nonsense by adding OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) for the parameter(s) that cause issues. Also see [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33698/parameter-sniffing-vs-variables-vs-recompile-vs-optimize-for-unknown) and [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Answer (score 3):

Local variables and parameters are entirely different things even though the query appears identical.  With local variables, SQL Server estimate row counts based on statistic average density values because the actual value is unknown at compile time.  However, in the case of a parameter, the actual parameter values are "sniffed" and the estimate gleaned from the statistics histogram for the actual value supplied.  The resultant execution plans may be different if the estimated number of rows differs significantly.

The symptoms you mention could be an indication that statistics are stale or the parameter sniffing issue mentioned.  Try updating stats on the table with FULLSCAN and rerunning the parameterized query to see if the plan is better:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS ON dbo.Books WITH FULLSCAN;
UPDATE STATISTICS ON dbo.BookPublishRegions WITH FULLSCAN;
```

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman. I ran those two statements and unfortunately the execution time did not improve.

Comment: @Ricky, you might try `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to make sure you get a new plan.  If the time is still bad, that rules out a sniffing issue.